# aggregating time series in R

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, time-series

I have the following OHLC data (by 3-minute intervals)

```
library(tseries)
library(xts)
library(quantmod)
> str(tickmin)
An ‘xts’ object from 2010-06-30 15:47:00 to 2010-09-08 15:14:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:8776, 1:5] 9215 9220 9205 9195 9195 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "zv.Open" "zv.High" "zv.Low" "zv.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL


>tickmin
2010-09-08 15:02:00        20
2010-09-08 15:04:00        77
2010-09-08 15:08:00        86
2010-09-08 15:11:00         7
2010-09-08 15:14:00        43
> start(tickmin)
[1] "2010-06-30 15:47:00 EDT"
> end(tickmin)
[1] "2010-09-08 15:14:00 EDT"
```

I am trying to aggregate it using the following:

```
> by <-timeSequence(from = start(tickmin), to = end(tickmin), format="%Y-%m-%d %H%M", by = "day")
>by
[61] [2010-08-29 19:47:00] [2010-08-30 19:47:00] [2010-08-31 19:47:00]
[64] [2010-09-01 19:47:00] [2010-09-02 19:47:00] [2010-09-03 19:47:00]
[67] [2010-09-04 19:47:00] [2010-09-05 19:47:00] [2010-09-06 19:47:00]
[70] [2010-09-07 19:47:00]

> aggregate(Vo(tickmin),by,sum)
Error: length(time(x)) == length(by[[1]]) is not TRUE
```

..would appreciate any suggestions on how I can fix the error.

Comment: Please indicate what package(s) you're using and the structure of your objects. Or do us even better, post a reproducible example.

Comment: if you need specifics of the example, I can do it, otherwise it is a lot of data for a reproducible example.

Comment: -1 Your example is entirely unclear.  `str(tickmin)` shows an xts object with 5 columns, yet `tickmin` only has one column when you print it on the next line.  The `timeSequence` function does not exist in any of the 3 packages you list.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'll explain your error and tell you how to fix it, but there's a better way to do what you're doing. So make sure you read my entire answer!

From the error message, the length of your `by` is not the same length as `Vo(tickmin)`.
You have to generate your `by` to have one value per corresponding value in `tickmin`, with the day.

As an example here I generate an `xts` object:

```
# generate a set of times from 2010-06-30 onwards at 20 minute intervals
tms <- as.POSIXct(seq(0,3600*24*30,by=60*20),origin="2010-06-30")
n   <- length(tms)
# generate volumes for those intervals, random 0 -- 100, turn into xts object
xts.ts <- xts(sample.int(100,n,replace=T),tms)
colnames(xts.ts)<-'Volume'
```

which yields:

```
> head(xts.ts)
                    Volume
2010-06-30 00:00:00     97
2010-06-30 00:20:00     78
2010-06-30 00:40:00     38
2010-06-30 01:00:00     86
2010-06-30 01:20:00     79
2010-06-30 01:40:00     55
```

To access the dates of `xts.ts` you use `index(xts.ts)` which gives a whole bunch of strings of the date, e.g. `"2010-07-30 00:00:00 EST"`.

To round these to the nearest day you can use `as.Date`:

```
> as.Date(index(xts.ts))
   [1] "2010-06-29" "2010-06-29" "2010-06-29" "2010-06-29" "2010-06-29"
    ....
```

## Solution to your problem

Then to use `aggregate` you do:

```
> aggregate(Vo(xts.ts),as.Date(index(xts.ts)),sum)

2010-06-29 1858
2010-06-30 3733
2010-07-01 3906
2010-07-02 3359
2010-07-03 3838
...
```

## Better solution to your problem

The `xts` package has functions `apply.daily`, `apply.monthly`, etc (use `ls('package:xts')` to see what functions it has -- there may be ones you're interested in).

`apply.daily(x,FUN,...)` does *exactly* what you want. See `?apply.daily`.
To use it you can do:

```
> apply.daily(xts.ts,sum)

                    Volume
2010-06-30 23:40:00   4005
2010-07-01 23:40:00   4093
2010-07-02 23:40:00   3419
2010-07-03 23:40:00   3737
...
```

Or if your `xts` object has other columns like `Open`, `Close` etc, you can do `apply.daily(xts.ts, function(x) sum(Vo(x)))`.

Note that the answers are slightly different using `apply.daily` to the `aggregate ... as.Date` method. That's because `apply.daily` goes daily from `start(xts.ts)` to `end(xts.ts)` (more or less) whereas `aggregate` just went by day from midnight to midnight.

Looking at your question, `apply.daily` seems to match most closely what you want to do (and is provided with `xts` anyway, so why not use it?)

Comment: thanks. I appreciate the explanation and your solution. I shall indeed check out apply.daily and work with that.

Comment: the first solution computes a different answer for each day than the second approach. The second seems to work correctly.

Comment: As.Date includes 20 min and 40 min after midnight in prior day.