# Remove time from XTS

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to compare different timeseries, by day.

Currently a typical XTS object looks like:

```
> vwap.crs
                    QUANTITY QUANTITY.1
2014-03-03 13:00:00 3423.500     200000
2014-03-04 17:00:00 3459.941    4010106
2014-03-05 16:00:00 3510.794    1971234
2014-03-06 17:00:00 3510.582     185822
```

now, i can strip the time out of the index as follows:

```
> round(index(vwap.crs),"day")
[1] "2014-03-04" "2014-03-05" "2014-03-06" "2014-03-07"
```

My question is, how do I replace the existing index in variable ***vwap.crs***, with the rounded output above?

EDIT: to.daily fixed it

Comment: you can use 'daily apply'

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886677/aggregating-time-series-in-r

Comment: apply.daily does not get rid of the time component in the index, unless i'm missing something

Comment: to.daily does remove the time component but also creates 4 column high,low etc. it is used for financial data

Answer (score 8):

This should do it

```
indexClass(vwap.crs) <- "Date"
```

Also, take a look at the code in `xts:::.drop.time`

---

You could also do it the way you're trying to do it if you use `index<-`

```
index(vwap.crs) <- round(index(vwap.crs),"day")
```

Comment: is it possible to also remove the day information so it is just year and month

Comment: @MySchizoBuddy You could do `index(vwap.crs) <- "yearmon"`.  But, you're a little limited beyond that because the index has to be `timeBased`.

Comment: indexClass() was deprecated with xts version 0.12-0 and replaced with tclass()