# Change 15 minute data to daily mean in R

Tags: r

I have 15 minute data that I want to change into daily mean.  I just listed the Columbia data below, but there are other sites (CR1 and CR2) where I didn't list that data.  I put my code at the bottom.  I get an error at

```
x <- xts(d[,-1], as.POSIXct(d[,1], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "EST"))
Error in as.POSIXct.default(d[, 1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "EST") : 
  do not know how to convert 'd[, 1]' to class “POSIXct”"
```

I'm pretty new to R so I'm sorry if the answer is something incredibly simple and I should have caught it.

```
 datetime         Discharge Columbia
 2014-01-19 22:00   6030    4.3
 2014-01-19 22:15   5970    4.28
 2014-01-19 22:30   5880    4.25
 2014-01-19 22:45   5830    4.23
 2014-01-19 23:00   5710    4.19
 2014-01-19 23:15   5620    4.16
 2014-01-19 23:30   5510    4.12
 2014-01-19 23:45   5400    4.08
 2014-01-20 00:00   5340    4.06
 2014-01-20 00:15   5290    4.04
 2014-01-20 00:30   5260    4.03
 2014-01-20 00:45   5210    4.01
 2014-01-20 01:00   5180    4
 2014-01-20 01:15   4990    3.93
 2014-01-20 01:30   4830    3.87
 2014-01-20 01:45   4810    3.86
 2014-01-20 02:00   4780    3.85
 2014-01-20 02:15   4780    3.85
 2014-01-20 02:30   4760    3.84
 2014-01-20 02:45   4760    3.84
 2014-01-20 03:00   4760    3.84
 2014-01-20 03:15   4760    3.84

USGS_Columbia_Data <- read.csv("~/Desktop/R/USGS_Columbia_Data.csv",header=TRUE)
## daily averages of the data
library(xts)
d <- structure(list(datetime = (USGS_Columbia_Data[1]), 
                Columbia = (USGS_Columbia_Data[3]), 
                CR1 = (USGS_Columbia_Data[5]), 
                CR2 = (USGS_Columbia_Data[7])), 
           .Names = c("datetime", "Columbia", "CR1", "CR2"), 
           row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
x <- xts(d[,-1], as.POSIXct(d[,1], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "EST"))
apply.daily(x, colMeans)
```

Comment: You should also have a look at the question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886677/aggregating-time-series-in-r

Comment: `aggregate(df[,c(3,4)], list(df$date), mean)` assuming `df` is the data you pasted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer works, apparently, but you can (and probably should) use `xts` for something like this. The problem is with your use of `structure(...)` to create the data frame. `USGS_Columbia_Data` is already a data frame. If you want to extract columns 1,3,5, and 7, do this:

```
d <- USGS_Columbia_Data[,c(1,3,5,7)]
colnames(d) <- c("datetime","Columbia","CR1","CR2"")
```

You may not need the second line if `USGS_Columbia_Data` already has those column names. Having done that, you can create a date-indexed `xts` object as follows:

```
x <- xts(d[,-1], as.Date(d[,1], format="%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Then either of the following will work: (note I'm using the `d` from your example here).

```
apply.daily(x,mean)
#            Discharge Columbia
# 2014-01-19   5743.75 4.201250
# 2014-01-20   4965.00 3.918571

aggregate(x,as.Date,mean)
#            Discharge Columbia
# 2014-01-19   5743.75 4.201250
# 2014-01-20   4965.00 3.918571
```

will work.

If you want to leave the index as `POSIXct`, use this:

```
x <- xts(d[,-1], as.POSIXct(d[,1], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
apply.daily(x,mean)
#                     Discharge Columbia
# 2014-01-19 23:45:00   5743.75 4.201250
# 2014-01-20 03:15:00   4965.00 3.918571
```

But note the index is the last time on each date, not the date itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut` and `aggregate`

```
# make certain datetime is class POSIXct
d$datetime <- as.POSIXct(d$datetime, tz='EST')

aggregate(list(Discharge = d$Discharge, Columbia = d$Columbia), list(time = cut(d$datetime, "1 day")), mean)

> aggregate(list(Discharge = d$Discharge, Columbia = d$Columbia), list(datetime = cut(t$datetime, "1 day")), mean)
        time Discharge Columbia
1 2014-01-19   5743.75 4.201250
2 2014-01-20   4965.00 3.918571
```