# Zoo error: length(time(x)) == length(by[[1]]) is not TRUE

Tags: r, zoo

I'm trying to work out evapotranspiration from climate data based on the Hargreaves Samani methodology using [this package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Evapotranspiration/Evapotranspiration.pdf)

The data I'm working on in csv format is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhbznsn37lgoots/OakParkR.csv?dl=0) and the code I'm using (with comments) is below

```
## Using Evapotranspiration package to get DAILY PE ###
require(Evapotranspiration)
require(zoo)

#load the constants required from the Evapotranspiration package
data("constants")

#converting the CSV to a zoo object
OakPark<- read.csv("mydata.csv", header=TRUE)

#Fill the blanks in the csv with NAs
na.fill(mydata,NA)

#convert to a zoo
mydata <- as.zoo(mydata)

#create a zoo series with the required variables
PE.data <- mydata[ ,c(3,5)]

#converting to a list as ET function works on a list
PE.data <- as.list(PE.data)

#change constants to the local values
constants$Elev = 62
constants$lat_rad = 0.9226

#defining the function
funname <- "HargreavesSamani"
class(PE.data) <- funname

#creating a new variable with the calculation
results <- ET(PE.data,constants)
```

The error then reads:

```
Error: length(time(x)) == length(by[[1]]) is not TRUE
```

I've looked at other help sections such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886677/aggregating-time-series-in-r) but can't see how I can implement this for it to work on this built-in HargreavesSamani function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ReadInputs` function in the same package (`Evapotranspiration`) package to pre-processing your data and construct the input data.
Do not create input data by yourself.

I got the same error when I tried to create input data by myself.
I believe using the `ReadInputs` function is the best solution to this problem.

Hope this help.

Comment: It has been so long since I asked this question it is great to see an answer, I can't remember how I got around the issue in the end, but this might help someone else. Thank you :)